# animate.css и jQuery

Tags: jquery

Почему при hover только один элемент анимируется? хотя id одинаковый дан. При помощи CSS при hover каждый элемент с одинаковым class/id анимируется. Как добиться этого на JS?

```js
$('#img_one').hover(function(){
  $('#img_one').addClass('animated infinite bounce');
}, function(){
  $('#img_one').removeClass('animated infinite bounce');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" id="img_one" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" id="img_one" />
```

Comment: Выбор по `id` подразумевает единственность элемента с таким `id`. Соответственно, `$('#img_one')` содержит ссылку только на один DOM элемент - первый найденный.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! В CSS всегда использую `class`, но сейчас проверил `<p id="img_one">TEST</p>
<p id="img_one">TEST2</p>` `#img_one:hover{
  color: red;
}`  Работает в CSS для обоих элементов. Еще такой вопрос: **"Выбор по id подразумевает единственность элемента с таким id"** это правило для всего JavaScript или только в jQuery?

Comment: В вопросе все-таки речь идет не о приложении css классов, а о выборке элементов. Допускаю, что в случае с `#img_one:hover{ color: red; }` действие идет в другую сторону - от известного элемента к стилю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых: надо использовать не `id`, a `class`. Ибо этих элементов много. При работе с `css` вы вроде должны были знать это.

Во-вторых: использовать `this` как указатель на элемент, над которым происходит событие.

```js
$('.img_one').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('animated infinite bounce');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('animated infinite bounce');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" class="img_one" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" class="img_one" />
```

Comment: Да, как раз в CSS всегда использую `class`. Только начинаю осваивать JS/jQuery и где-то прочитал, что для манипуляции с DOM лучше использовать `id`. Ваш вариант решил мою проблему, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.img_one').hover(function(){
  $('.img_one').addClass('animated infinite bounce');
}, function(){
  $('.img_one').removeClass('animated infinite bounce');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" class="img_one" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="img" class="img_one" />
```